# Not showing gridview rows in scrollview

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:id="@id/scrollView">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"       
            android:background="@drawable/accomplishmentshelf">  
            <GoalTactics.AccomplishmentsGridView
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
                 android:gravity="center_vertical"
                 android:columnWidth="100dip"
                 android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                 android:horizontalSpacing="30dip"
                 android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                 android:verticalSpacing="0dip"
                 android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
                 android:isScrollContainer="false"
                 android:numColumns="4"
                 android:id="@+id/accomplishmentsGridView1"
                />
       </FrameLayout>
     </ScrollView>
```

I need to show my gridview at scrollview, but it's dont work and shown 1 row, other rows dont shows. How to solve this problem?
i need layout like that: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uq2Jw.jpg)

if i use linearlayout i have that: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg9Ag.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could use GridView instead. GridView is scrollable. There is a simple code for your reference.

xaml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        //LoadApplication(new App());

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);

        var gridview = FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gridView1);
        gridview.Adapter = new gridViewAdapter(this);

    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
public class gridViewAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    Context context;
    public gridViewAdapter(Context c)
    {
        context = c;
    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get { return thumbIds.Length; }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null)
        {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.LayoutParameters = new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85);
            imageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
            imageView.SetPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        else
        {
            imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
        }

        imageView.SetImageResource(thumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    int[] thumbIds = {
    Resource.Drawable.pink, Resource.Drawable.pink,
    Resource.Drawable.pink, Resource.Drawable.pink,
    Resource.Drawable.pink, Resource.Drawable.pink,
    Resource.Drawable.pink, Resource.Drawable.pink,
    Resource.Drawable.pink, Resource.Drawable.pink,
    Resource.Drawable.pink, Resource.Drawable.pink,
    Resource.Drawable.pink, Resource.Drawable.pink,
    Resource.Drawable.pink, Resource.Drawable.pink,
    Resource.Drawable.pink, Resource.Drawable.pink,
    Resource.Drawable.pink, Resource.Drawable.pink,
    Resource.Drawable.pink, Resource.Drawable.pink
};

}
```

Comment: If i use linearlayout my background  just stretches to fill the entire page and dont scrolling, but not more than it, but I need it my background to be completely the size of the table itself and the background and elements in it scroll.I attached a photo of what I need and what I have when using linearlayout

Comment: @DivinegdkD Can you share your `GoalTactics.AccomplishmentsGridView` code? If it achieved by the `Android.Widget.GridView`, it could be scrolled.